# Applying a predicate to all elements of a sequence

Tags: scala

How should I write a function that returns true if all elements in a list satisfy a given predicate?

Considering list below and any predicate:

```
val set = List(3, 4, 5, 6, 10)
```

I assume I need to write something similar to:

```
def checkListElements(list parameters... ): Boolean = true if condition meet else false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to write one yourself, you can use [`Iterator.forall`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator@forall(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean):

```
scala> var list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
set: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> list.forall(i => i % 2 == 0)
res0: Boolean = false
```

A little shorter using syntax sugar:

```
scala> list.forall(_ % 2 == 0) // Underscore will expand to i => i % 2 == 0
res2: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I rewrite this as so It returns true if a single element satisfy the condition.

Comment: @user2300867 Use `Iterator.exists` instead.

Comment: @user2300867 Another useful approach will be reading the corresponding API docs.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Or doing a little experimentation in the REPL, you'll find those fast enough.

Comment: Got it. makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Could I still use .forall or .exists if I want predicate to be a parameter of type T=>Boolean

Comment: @user2300867 If the collection is of type `T`, then sure.